# PHP - Uncaught SoapFault exception - how to ignore it and continue while loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to ignore errors and continue my script but I can't do it. This is my code:

```
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient('http://allegro.pl/uploader.php?wsdl');
    $version = $client->doQueryAllSysStatus(1, $allegro_user_webapi_key);
    $version = get_object_vars($version[0]);
    $session = $client->doLoginEnc($allegro_username, base64_encode(hash('sha256', $allegro_user_pass, true)), 1, $allegro_user_webapi_key, $version['ver-key']);

    $i = 0;
    $tab = array();
    while( (time() - $time) >= 240 )
    {
        $i++;

        $get = $client->doShowUser($allegro_user_webapi_key, 1, 15, ''); // HERE IS A PROBLEM
        $tab[] = $get['userLogin'];
    }   

    echo $i.'<br><br>'."\n\n";
    var_dump($tab);
}
catch(TemplateException $e)
{
    // continue
}
```

When I add "@" here:

```
$get = @$client->doShowUser($allegro_user_webapi_key, 1, 15, '');
```

It doesn't work... When I remove try and catch it also doesn't work fine. How I can definitely ignore these errors and continue my script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your try and catch you are catching exceptions of the type `TemplateException`.

This won't catch the exception that is thrown, because it is a `SoapFaultException`

```
try {
  ...
} catch (TemplateException $e) {
  // do something when a TemplateException is thrown

} catch (SoapFaultException $e) {
  // do something when a SoapFaultException is thrown

} catch (Exception $e) {
  // catch any other exception that is thrown
}
```

The try catch are processed in order ( `TemplateException` > `SoapFaultException` > .. )

If you only want to catch the `SoapFaultException`, you can do this:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (SoapFaultException $e) {
  // do something when a SoapFaultException is thrown

}
```

If you want to catch all exceptions, regardless of the type:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // catch all exceptions that are thrown
}
```

---

If you only want to catch exceptions triggered by `doShowUser` and still continue your `while` loop, then you'll need to move the try catch

```
while( (time() - $time) >= 240 )
{
    try {
       $i++;

       // HERE IS A PROBLEM
       $get = $client->doShowUser($allegro_user_webapi_key, 1, 15, '');
       $tab[] = $get['userLogin'];

    } catch (Exception $e) {
       // do nothing
    }        

}
```

Comment: Now it's doesn't print error but it stop my loop :/

Comment: Did you put the try catch inside your while loop?

Answer (score 0):

put the try catch in the loop

```
while( (time() - $time) <= 240 )
   {
   $i++;
   try{
      $get = $client->doShowUser($allegro_user_webapi_key, 1, 15, ''); // HERE IS A PROBLEM
   }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
      // do smthing
   }
    $tab[] = $get['userLogin'];
}
```

Comment: Now it's doesn't print error but it stop my loop :/

Comment: Exceptions caught inside a loop don't implicitly break the loop